# Как в GoogleMaps APIs (js) узнать нахожусь ли я на проложенном пути?

Tags: api, google-maps-api, google-maps, карты, google-maps-api-2

Такая вот задача, есть карта, на ней проложен путь. Мне нужно определить нахожусь ли я на проложенном пути, то есть точка моего местонахождения прикасается к пути. Под "нахожусь ли я" - имею ввиду данные GPS. 
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [isLocationOnEdge](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge):

> To determine whether a point falls on or near a polyline, or on or
>   near the edge of a polygon, pass the point, the polyline/polygon, and
>   optionally a tolerance value in degrees to
>   google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(). The function returns
>   true if the distance between the point and the closest point on the
>   line or edge falls within the specified tolerance.

Вольный перевод:

> Для определения лежит ли точка на кривой или вблизи края многоугольника, передайте точку, кривую/полигон и необязательно значение погрешности в градусах в google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(). Функция возвращает истину если расстояние между переданной точкой и точкой на линии или краю многоугольника удовлетворяет условию с заданной погрешностью.